# Use of ActionBarSherlock library get error "R class can not be resolved"

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) to implement action bar for **Android 2.1** platform.

But in Eclipse, no matter I import existing project from download **ActionBarSherlock** library or create new project from the download library, I always get error of "**R can not be resolved**". Then I notice that there is no `R.java` file under `gen/` folder. I tried to clean the project, but it does not help... Anyone can help me on how to get rid of this **ActionBarSherlock** library?

Comment: Sounds like your build path is not setup correctly.  Did you add the source of Sherlock to your project and include it in the build path in the project setup?

Comment: No, I mean the download Sherlock has this R can not be resolved problem. I have not yet started to use it in my own project .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActionBarSherlock (v3.x) requires that you compile with Android 3.2. The reason you are not seeing an `R.java` file is that you are likely using a previous version for compilation which means some of the styles that are used on Android 3.0+ cannot be found.

Make sure you are building with Android 3.2, target API 11+ in your manifest, and are using JDK 1.6. Those are the common pitfalls with compilation of the library.

Comment: Then, it does not make any sense for me to use sherlock anymore, because I want to implement action bar on Android 2.1 . Many people suggest sherlock could be used, but now you said not... I am confused, can you suggest me how can I implement action bar on Android 2.1 API 7 ??

Comment: You only *build* with 3.2. You can still run on 2.1.

Comment: Do you mean I change the minSDK to 11+ in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: You need to compile with 3.x so that the library can have access to the native `ActionBar` class. As @ReubenScratton said, you can still run your application on Android 1.6 and up. Your `minSdkVersion` can be as low as 4.

Comment: M taregt sdk is 16 and jdk 1.6 ... still im not able to get R file